# How many root(s) does these equation have?

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

I am in doubt with this concept , the order of $x-1=0$  is $1$ and equation has one root . $(x-1)^2=0 \to x=1,1 $  but ,what about below equations ?
$$x-1=0 \to x=1\text{ one time}\\(x-1)^3=0 \to x=1\text{ 3 times}\\|x-1|=0\\\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^7}=0\\(x-1)\ln x=0\\(x-1)^{4.5}=0$$  Can you suggest me a reference ?

thanks in advance

Comment: What you have observed is that this business of counting roots by multiplicity does not apply outside of very restricted contexts, such as the context of polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

What is meant by " $y=x^2$ has two roots at $x=0$" is that $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=0$, $y''(0)\ne0$ so the first $n-1$ derivatives are 0, and the $n$th isn't 0

So for your examples, $x-1$ is once,

$(x-1)^3$ is 3 times,

$|x-1|$ 1 time or doesn't make sense,

$(x-1)^{7/3}$ 3 times,

$(x-1)\ln(x)$ 2 times,

$(x-1)^{4.5}$ 5 times or doesn't make sense.

And for $x^n$ it's $\operatorname{ceiling}(n)$ times.

Comment: How can you say that $(x-1)^{7/3}$ has $x=1$ as a root of order three ? It is meaningless. As said by @Lee Mosher, we have to restrict to the class of polynomials.

Comment: Well it may be useless but if it did have an order then 3 would be the most valid answer, so it must be 3, correct?

Comment: If it can be given a meaning it is 2, not 3. Here is why. Let $f(x):=(x-1)^{7/3};$ You can check that $f'(x)=\tfrac73(x-1)^{4/3}$ thus $f'(1)=0$, then $f''(x)=\tfrac{28}{9}(x-1)^{1/3}$ ; we still have $f''(1)=0$. Till that point, $x=1$ is a root of order at least two ($x=1$ is a root of f, f' and f''), but $f'''(x)=\tfrac{28}{27(x-1)^{2/3}}$ is undefined in $x=1$, thus $f'''(1)$ will never be 0.

Comment: @Jacob Claassen: can you cite a reference  ?

Comment: @Khosrotash, sorry, this is something I came across a while ago and went "huh, interesting", and forgot about it until now, I have no idea where I even saw it.

Comment: @JeanMarie, no, because $y=x^3$ has 3 roots at $x=0$, despite $y'''(0)\ne0$.

Answer (score 2):

An attempt to answer the question!

For a polynomial degree $n$ the fundamental theorem of algebra ensures $n$ complex roots with multiplicity. And it can be factorized:
$$p_n(x)=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots (x-x_n)=0.$$
For example:
$$(x-1)^3=(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)=0,$$
$$(x-1)(x^2+1)=(x-1)(x-i)(x+i)=0.$$
Also when squared (taken square root), the number of roots doubles (reduces by half). For example:
$$(x-1)^4=0 \ \ (4 \ \ roots); (x-1)^2=0 \ \ (2 \ \ roots).$$
Extending this principle, we can hypothesize: if the left hand side function can be factorized by binomials of $x\pm c, c=const$, then the number of roots is equal to the number of binomial factors. For example:
$$\sqrt{(x-1)^2}=|x-1|=0 \Rightarrow (x-1)=0 \ \ (1 \ \ root)$$
$$|x-1|=2 \Rightarrow (x+1)\cdot (x-3)=0 \ \ (2 \ \ roots)$$
$$\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^7}=0 \Rightarrow (x-1)^2 \sqrt[3]{x-1}=0 \ \ (2<n<3 \ \ roots? \ inapplicable \ \ in \ \ N)$$
$$(x-1)\ln{x}=0 \Rightarrow (x-1)(x-1)=0 \ \ (2 \ \ roots)$$
Note: In the last example $\ln{x} \sim (x-1), x\to 1$ is used.